# i want to save json file on mogodb using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

i want to save json file format on mongodb but i am unable to do that ,when i am trying it gives me only file name on my database ,please help me

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
    var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        fileName: Object
    });

    var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);
 
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Upload.html");
    });

    app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new User(req.body);
    myData.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send("Name saved to database" + item);
            res.json(item);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
    });
```

Comment: You have to use a module like `multer` to handle files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: you need to serialize the file

Comment: why not just store the actual json in mongoDB instead of saving a json file???